# Need a cool hotkey for my hidden website-login

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, hotkeys, backend

I am developing a CMS. One of the greatest everyday annoyances when working with it is that when you are on a front-end page, not logged in, and want to make a change, you need to go to the back-end login first, log in, and then navigate to the page you want to change.

I would like to introduce a smart little function that pops up a log-in screen when you hit a certain key combination. I have already set this up with double Ctrl. I have come to realize, though, that I hit that key so frequently that the login pops up unwanted, something that must not happen of course.

So, I am asking for your ideas for a clever key combination.

I am looking for a key combination that is:

- Elegant and easy to memorize (this is why I liked double Ctrl very much)
- Time considerations (Press key X, then Y after 1 second) are possible
- Must not be mapped to any browser function of course. I realize this cannot be excluded 100% but obviously, Ctrl+A or Alt+Tab would be nonstarters.
- Works on all keyboards (Mac included, but I'm willing to handle the apple special keys)
- Extremely unlikely to be hit accidentally
- Other clever ideas like simple mouse gestures are also welcome.

It can be argued that this poses a decrease in security, as the URL to the back-end login is made available in front-end pages and loses the additional protection by being obscure. I may address that later using a cookie that identifies CMS users' machines but it is not the issue right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh  you just KNOW you have to go for the [Konami Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code)!

There are several websites that implement it - take a look at [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Konami_code_websites).

I know it's not the simplest, but it does have the geek factor ;)

Comment: I won't use the Konami Code but accepting the answer as the most hilarious. :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just have a "Editor Login" link at the bottom of the page?

It won't be any less secure and will be a lot easier to use. I can see the solution you are trying to use causing all kinds of odd problems down the road...

If you really really want it "hidden", you can just make it white text on a white background or something.

Comment: Basically, you're right, but I want to experiment with this. I permanently visible "editor login" would be standing out too much, the site in question is very simple design-wise.

Answer (score 0):

What about the simple ` key at the top left corner of your keyboard? This is often used in games to get into a console mode (counter strike, left 4 dead, etc). It is mac/windows/linux compatible and shouldn't interfere with anything in the browser.

Comment: Won't work because it's not consistent throughout locales. On my keyboard (german) the top left key is ^.

Comment: But presuming he just meant the tilde key <kbd>~</kbd> that does still appear in every locale, just not at the top left.  So possibly use that?

Comment: Mmm, too difficult to type in, at least with a german layout: You need Alt Gr for that.